# Does calling setOnClickListener from multiple classes result in only one callback?

Tags: android, listview, android-view, onitemclicklistener, onclicklistener

I'd like to be able to change `OnItemClickListener` for a `ListView` dynamically.  However, the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29) isn't clear about whether or not this is acceptable, nor about what the outcome will be if I do.

What I would like is that if I call `listView.setOnItemClickListener()` from one class, and then later again from a different class, that only the more recent class gets the callback.

This question incidentally could also apply to [`SetOnClickListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29).

The API might be implemented to behave this way, but it might instead be implemented such that all classes that called `setOnItemClickListener` get the callback.

Which behavior is actually implemented by the Android API?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the AdapterView.setOnItemClickListener() source code [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/AdapterView.java):

```
/**
 * Register a callback to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has
 * been clicked.
 *
 * @param listener The callback that will be invoked.
 */
public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mOnItemClickListener = listener;
}
```

In Java world, generally a setter method will flush the previous value and set the object's instance variable to the new value. So the behavior you are talking about is ***only the more recent class gets the callback.***

---

> it might instead be implemented such that all classes that called setOnItemClickListener get the callback.

In Java world, this is also possible, in this case, as a good OOP practice, we usually name it addOnItemClickListener(), which is more specifically, use a List of Listener store/manage multiply listeners within the actual implementation. This is not how AdapterView.setOnItemClickListener() is implemented in API.

Comment: After posing the question, I had thought about the distinction in nomenclature of adding a listener vs. setting a listener, and figured it would be a misnomer if it didn't behave as I had expected.  This seems more like a human language semantic than a Java-specific convention.  I think I just expected to read something specifying this in the API documentation.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

You are free to `setOnItemClickListener()` as many times as you like, only the most recent OnItemClickListener will be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
String className = "MyOnClickListener";
obj = (OnClickListenerInterface)( Class.forName( className).newInstance() );
```

You will have to create an interface for the listener but you can implement the different listener in different clasess, and then called each one of them dynamically like is shown in this code portion.